# JavaScript/jQuery "if" condition syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm attempting to evaluate a class to see if it contains some text in my click handler, but I can't get my code to act properly. What am I missing?

The `if` statement is looking to see whether the class of the clicked object has the word "headline" in it.

```
$('[class^=edit_]').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).attr('class');
    var field = element.split(/_(.+)/)[1];
    if ($(this).attr('[class*=headline]'))
    {
        alert("headline");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("not headline");
    };
});
```

Is it possible to construct my `if` statement with something that evaluates the `var field = element.split(/_(.+)/)[1];` since that is really where the information resides.

Something like:

```
if (element *= "headline"){do this};
```

I'm not sure I understand all of the "evaluators" that exist in JavaScript to know if I can evaluate a string like that.

Comment: I do not understand this question. Maybe I'm just stupid, but at this point in time I believe that the question is lacking in detail and coherence.

Comment: I don't understand what the if statement is supposed to be testing...

Comment: The if statement is looking to see whether the class of the clicked object has the word "headline" in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon re-reading your question, there's an even simpler approach, just check the [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) for the string you want using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), like this:

```
if (this.className.indexOf('headline') != -1)
```

---

*Previous answer:*
The closest version to what you have, checking if an element matching a selector is [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like this:

```
if ($(this).is('[class*=headline]'))
```

But there's another method more appropriate here (if you're checking for a full class, not part of one), you can use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like this:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('headline'))
```

Comment: `hasClass()` might not work in this case, assuming his class name is edit_headline for example, `is('[class*=headline]')` would match, but not `hasClass('headline')`.

Comment: Nick, unfortunately, my class has other words separated by `_` so I'm trying to decipher if the full class name has the word "headline" anywhere in it.

Comment: @Seldaek - Right, that's why there's the note on the second version :) @Ofeargall - the first `.is()` version will work then :)

Comment: Thanks, Nick. `if ($(this).is('[class*=headline]'))` was exactly what I was looking for. I'm glad you were able to see what I was trying to achieve even if my question was somewhat incomplete.

Comment: @Ofeargall - welcome :) look above, I added an even cheaper way of doing this, now that I'm *fully* aware of what you're after :)

Comment: @Nick, so the logic goes: "index the words in this class name and if the word 'headline' isn't not in the list do the first thing in the if statement" correct?

Comment: @Ofeargall - mm not really, `.indexOf()` is looking for the string, so it's saying "is the string "headline" found in my `class` attribute at all?"

Comment: Personally I prefer `if (this.className.test(/headline/))` which I feel expresses the intention more directly and is therefore more readable. It is a bit more expensive than indexOf though but not by much since the expression given to the regexp engine is not pathological.

Comment: @Nick, thank you for explaining the logic. It helps me recall these types of tricks later. Is there an operator call `idName` as well, or is this for classes only? Again, thanks.

Comment: @Ofeargall - It's just `.id` for that, `.className` is different specifically because `class` is a reserved word :)